# Getting a response from REST service via PL/SQL (Oracle)

Tags: json, oracle, rest, plsql

This is my function which should return the response with some values to me.

```
create FUNCTION EVALUTION_VALUES(data clob) RETURN clob IS
  http_req            UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  http_resp           UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  resp_text           VARCHAR2(4000);
  url                 VARCHAR2(400) := 'http://xxxxxx.xxx:9000/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max';
  description_value   VARCHAR2(400);
  result_clob         CLOB;
BEGIN
  http_req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url, 'GET');

  http_resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(http_req);

  UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(http_resp, resp_text);

  SELECT JSON_VALUE(resp_text, '$.description')
  INTO description_value
  FROM DUAL;

  result_clob := TO_CLOB('Description value is: ') || TO_CLOB(description_value);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result_clob);

  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(http_resp);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
    RETURN TO_CLOB('An error occurred: ') || TO_CLOB(SQLERRM);  -- Return error message
END EVALUTION_VALUES;
/
```

The endpoint is valid

[image]

But this is the error I'm getting

**An error occurred: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed**

What could be the issue and how to fix this. Is my approach wrong?